# How to find the third moment $E[X^3]$ of Gamma Distribution?

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

I'm having trouble with the following question. So far I've tried to integrate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^3f(x) \, dx$$
but I end up with a horrible looking integral (I assume integration by parts won't fix this...)

[image]

Comment: That horrible looking integral is really your friend.  Stare hard at the formula in the Q3 prob statement and look at your integral again and (if needed) look up the basic facts about the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the horrible looking integral because you've already done it before, i.e. it's the SAME integral that you evaluate when you find the normalizing constant in the Gamma density. The only difference is that it has $\alpha+3$ where $\alpha$ had been, so you just need to put $\alpha+3$ where $\alpha$ had been in the value of the integral. NOTE a simple point of logic: When it is said that a certain integral is equal to $\dfrac 1 {\lambda^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)},$ that is true if $\alpha$ is ANY positive number at all; and $\alpha+3$ is a$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$positive number; hence it is true of $\alpha+3.$ Thus you get that integral almost for free because of what you already did when you find the normalizing constant. For specifics, see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, what is meant by the "normalising constant..."?

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths : A normalizing "or 'normalising' " constant is a constant by which one must multiply a function to make its integra equal to $1.$ Thus one observes that $$ \int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t} \, dt = \Gamma(\alpha) $$(that is usually taken to be the definition of the Gamma function) and one multiplies $t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t}$ by $1/\Gamma(\alpha),$ getting $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t},  $$ a function whose integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is $1. \qquad$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = \frac {\Gamma(\alpha)} {\lambda^\alpha}. \tag 1 \\[15pt]
\text{Therefore } & \int_0^\infty x^3 \cdot x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty x^{(\alpha+ 3)-1} e^{-\lambda x} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \text{the same thing as (1) except that } \alpha-3 \\
& \qquad \text{appears where } \alpha \text{ had been, and therefore} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac {\Gamma(\alpha+3)} {\lambda^{\alpha+3}}.
\end{align}

(**Explicit point about logic:** The equality $(1)$ is true if $\alpha$ is any positive number at all. Since $\alpha+3$ is a positive number, it is true if $\alpha+3$ appears where $\alpha$ had been.)

So first use that in evaluating the relevant integral.

Then use this: $\Gamma(\alpha+3) = (\alpha+2)(\alpha+1)\alpha\Gamma(\alpha).$

(This same sort of thing applies to finding moments of the Beta distribution.)

Comment: Where did you get the first line from? Is it a standard formula?

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths Do you know about Laplace transforms? The first integral in this answer is the Laplace transform of $x^{\alpha - 1}$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson : That may be of interest but it's not actually needed here.

Comment: I think I must be missing something obvious, I thought $\Gamma(\alpha):= \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha -1} e^{-t} dt$ and under the substitution $t = \lambda x$ we have $\Gamma(\alpha) = \lambda^{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x} dx$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I have heard about them but not in this context, could you point me in the right direction to find out more?

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths : If you've seen the Gamma distribution then I would think you've seen that. It is $$ (\lambda x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda\,dx) \text{ for } x\ge0. $$ The integral of that must be $1.$ And that's what line $(1)$ in my answer says. $\qquad$

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths : $\ldots\,$and, as JessicaK's comment points out, the substitution $t = \lambda x$ reduces that to $$ t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t} \, dt, $$ whose integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is $\Gamma(\alpha). \qquad$

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths : I fixed an important detail in the answer: $\Gamma(\alpha)$ should have been in the numerator.

Comment: @JessicaK : I was guilty of a disastrous typo: I put $\Gamma(\alpha)$ in the denominator where it should have been in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:

\begin{align}
E[X^3] &= \int_0^\infty x^3 f_X(x) dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^\alpha x^{3+\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda^3}\int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^{\alpha + 3} x^{3+\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+3)}{\lambda^3 \Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^{\alpha + 3} x^{3+\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha+3)} dx \\
\end{align}

Comment: This seems like more of a sketch than a hint.